# How to find out the square sequence in the number string?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to find out sequence of square patterns in the number string and eliminate it?

Example,

Input: 1232416256789
Output: 123789

Comment: Please clarify logic. I see why 4 and 16 and 256 are eliminated, but why also second 2 is eliminated? I would expect output to be 1232789

Comment: I want to eliminate continuous square patterns in this case "2416256"